# how test touch interaction on simulator of app build using Microsoft surface 2.0 sdk and XNA framework on windows 7

Tags: touch, pixelsense

I am developing an application using Microsoft Surface 2.0 SDK and XAN framework. I have developed an app before release I want to test touch gesture working properly on actual device, as I am not having device.

So can anybody know how test an app for touch interaction with application. I have developed this simple app using visual studio 2010, Microsoft surface 2.0 and on windows 7 operating system. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very bad answer, but it works for me.

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Touch;

//in constructor
TouchPanel.EnabledGestures = GestureType.Tap;
//In method
 if (TouchPanel.IsGestureAvailable)
        {
            GestureSample gesture = TouchPanel.ReadGesture();
            if (gesture.GestureType == GestureType.Tap)
            {  
             //Do something
            }
         }
```

Only detects the touch upon release of the screen. I'm currently looking for a better implementation.